# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System._COMObject' to interface type

Tags: ssis

I have 3 SSIS packages. Two out of the 3 SSIS packages work perfectly, the third. Which is a copy of the 2nd one, except changing connection strings keeps throwing the problem:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSObject100'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{D4E5AF42-7999-473C-8082-6EFC676953C4}' failed due to the following error: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)).

It has been doing this ever since I copied the package over. I have followed through online guides and run the regsvr32 dts.dll and this said it was successful but nothing has changed. I still get the error, why is this?

The SSIS package seems to validate my containers, it takes a long time to do this compared to the other two and then fails later on in the validation throwing the above error message.

Answer (score 5):

You can't just copy the package, but you need additionally to change the name and generate new **GUID** (which identifies the COM object) for this package. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345176.aspx) MSDN article for more info.

Comment: My second package is a copy of the third with different connection strings and it works fine. I will create a new package tomorrow and copy the logic itself over. Cheers. I'll let you know how it turns out

Comment: This did not fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is the workaround: Solution Explorer -> right click project ->properties->debugging->Run64bitRuntime->set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps others. The solution worked for me:

1. I registered the assembly using the `gacutil.exe`. My SSIS project target server version was SQL 2012. So, I was using the `DTSPipelineWrap.dll` version 11.0. I opened the `"Developer Command Prompt for VS2015"` in Administrator mode, then typed the following command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll"`
2. Then from my SSIS script task, References--> I removed the existing DTSPipelineWrap which was using the assembly from the location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll". Then in the References folder, right click-->Add Reference-->Browse find the assembly from the location `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll"`
3. Click Ok. Rebuild the code and executed the package. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is was a validation overload/timeout, the package contained references to hundreds of tables.

Opening the offending data flow forced re-validation and cleared the error.

Answer (score 0):

Project --> Properties --> Configuration Properties --> Debugging

and then change `Run64BitRuntime` to `False` under `Debug Options`

[image: 1]

Answer (score -1):

In case this might help someone: I got this error due to timeout issues caused by a poorly optimised query. There was nothing inherently wrong with the SSIS package and it ran fine once i fixed the problem in the DB Source.